# why is a let binding is ignored in compiled function?

Tags: lexical-scoping, let-binding, dynamic-scoping, defvar

I have this function which works perfectly in an uncompiled function. It should let-bind the variable `bibtex-completion-bibliography` to the result of `(org-ref-find-bibliography)`.

```lisp
    (defun org-ref-valid-keys ()
      "Return a list of valid bibtex keys for this buffer.
    This is used a lot in `org-ref-cite-activate' so it needs to be
    fast, but also up to date."
      ;; this seems to be needed, but we don't want to do this every time
      (unless bibtex-completion-display-formats-internal
        (bibtex-completion-init))
    
      ;; I don't fully understand what is happening here.
      (let ((bibtex-completion-bibliography (org-ref-find-bibliography)))
        (cl-loop for entry in (bibtex-completion-candidates)
             collect
             (cdr (assoc "=key=" (cdr entry))))))
```

What should happen is (org-ref-find-bibliography) gets a list of bibliography files if they are defined in a buffer (it defaults to a variable setting if they are not), and then let-binds that list to bibtex-completion-bibliography, and the keys are extracted from (bibtex-completion-candidates) which uses bibtex-completion-bibliography to get keys from those files. This works fine when the function is not compiled.

When the function is compiled, the keys end up coming from the default list of bibtex files, and not from the list defined by (org-ref-find-bibliography) (which still does the right thing). It is as if the let binding does not work.

If I debug the function, or re-evaluate it, it works fine, it only does not work when called from the compiled function. It also works if I delete all the .elc files in the package.

All the bibtex-completion* functions and variables are defined in the external library bibtex-completion.

I have  `-*- lexical-binding: t; -*-` in the first line of that file.

What could be causing this?

extra details:

```
GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, NS appkit-2022.60 Version 11.5 (Build 20G71)) of 2021-07-29
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're compiling the file using lexical binding, so I *suspect* the problem is that your file does neither of the following:

- `(defvar bibtex-completion-bibliography)`
- `(require 'bibtex-completion)`

either of which would tell the code in your file that `bibtex-completion-bibliography` is a dynamic variable.

Without that information, the following creates a *lexical* binding for `bibtex-completion-bibliography` (which is distinct from the symbol by that name):

```
  (let ((bibtex-completion-bibliography (org-ref-find-bibliography)))
    (cl-loop for entry in (bibtex-completion-candidates)
```

You then call `(bibtex-completion-candidates)` which is undoubtedly looking at the dynamic variable `bibtex-completion-bibliography` which was *not* set by your code.

When you're testing all of this interactively, I imagine that `bibtex-completion-bibliography` is getting declared as dynamic along the way, thus causing your code to do what you had intended.

In summary, when you're using lexical binding, it's crucial that *all* dynamic variables are declared as such, either by `require`ing the library which defines them, or else by explicitly declaring them with the `(defvar FOO)` syntax (with only a single parameter, defvar does not define a variable `FOO`, but rather says that references to `FOO` in the same file are to the *dynamic* variable by that name).

---

> When ‘require’ is used at top level in a file, it takes effect when you byte-compile that file as well as when you load it.  This is in case the required package contains macros that the byte compiler must know about.  It also avoids byte compiler warnings for functions and variables defined in the file loaded with ‘require’.

-- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Named Features`

> Effectively ‘require’ is automatically ‘eval-and-compile’, the package is loaded both when compiling and executing.

-- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Eval During Compile`

Comment: Some days these things still make me feel like an amateur! Do you still have to defvar these if you (require 'bibtex-completion) in that file (which is where those variables and functions are declared)?

Comment: No, the `require` should be sufficient.  I'll amend my answer, because I've overstated the necessity to declare things.

Comment: When would you choose to defvar/declare-function over just using require?

Comment: You might not wish to `require` a library if it's possible that it won't actually be needed.  If your code was instead depending on autoloading or hooks rather than forcibly loading the library, then you would need to declare things explicitly.  (I do this quite a lot in my own config, as I'm generally configuring things if and when they are loaded, rather than forcibly loading them up front.)

Comment: If you `rgrep` your config for `(defvar [[:alnum:]-]\+)` you'll probably find a bunch of examples.

Comment: Also, note carefully the "at top level" in the first of those quotes about `require` from the manual.  If you *conditionally* `require` something, or do it within a function body, then the call is not a top-level call and the byte-compiler will *not* automatically ensure that the required library is loaded.  In that situation you would need to `eval-and-compile` the `require` statement to ensure the definitions were known to the byte-compiler (or else use `defvar`).